# Round robin of producers/consumers with RxJs

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to implement a kind of multiple producers multiple consumers queue with RxJs. Basically I have some producers of jobs and some consumers (workers). I want to take one job and send it to the next available worker in a round robin fashion. Until now I got this

```
let src = Rx.Observable.from(this.producers).mergeMap(
  (producer) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(producer.getJobs).mergeMap((jobs) => Rx.Observable.from(jobs))
);


let tgt = Rx.Observable.from(this.workers).repeatWhen(complete => complete.delay(2000));
```

I want to connect both. I think with something like takeuntil. Workers executeJobs by calling worker.executeJob(job).

Comment: Is there any real reason why the list of workers is an Observable as opposed to being a plain old list?

Comment: It comes from a normal array, so I think there's no problem getting rid of the second observable.